# Azure IOT error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol json_parse_string referenced in function IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_step1and2

Tags: c++, windows, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am learning how to use Azure IOT-hub to use with C++ on windows.

For my sample I downloaded below things from "Manage NuGet Packages" in Visual Studio 2017

```
Microsoft.Azure.C.SharedUtility 
Microsoft.Azure.IoTHub.IoTHubClient 
Microsoft.Azure.IoTHub.HttpTransport
```

I have a sample C++ code file where I included following iot files.

```
#include <future>
#include <time.h>
#include "azure_c_shared_utility/platform.h"
#include "iothub_client.h"
#include "iothubtransporthttp.h"
```

In the C++ code I have added only the below lines

```
std::string connStr = " . . .";
IOTHUB_CLIENT_HANDLE iothubclienthHandle;
if (platform_init() != 0)
{
    printf("Failed initializing IOT platform.\r\n");
    return;
}

iothubclienthandle = IoTHubClient_CreateFromConnectionString(connStr.c_str(), HTTP_Protocol);
if (iothubclienthandle == nullptr)
{
    printf("Failed IoTHubClient_Create\r\n");
}
```

But while building the it gives me linker error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol json_parse_string referenced in function IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_step1and2
```

What else which file/library I need to include in my visual studio project to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is with 1.2.2 version of sdk.
I took the older version 1.1.32 and it compiled fine.

Comment: Changing Microsoft.Azure.IoTHub.HttpTransport to version 1.2.0  will be also ok.